# How to Parse Xml with Structure in ios

Tags: ios

I know how to parse some XML structures but I am currently trying to parse this specific xml structure thats a bit different to what I am used to.

But now I'm working with some xml like so..
Can you please help me out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EssentialPhoneNumbers>
    <Department>
        <Name>Direct sales department</Name>
        <Phone>03-6380000</Phone>
        <Hours>Sunday - Thursday 20:00 to 8:30. Fridays and holiday eves: 8:00 to 12:00</Hours>
        <Contacts>
            <Contact>
                <Name>Inquiries about purchasing life and health insurance</Name>
                <Phone>03-6380390</Phone>
                <Fax>NA</Fax>
                <Hours>NA</Hours>
            </Contact>
            <Contact>
                <Name>Inquiries about purchasing car insurance, apartment and office</Name>
                <Phone>03-6380350</Phone>
                <Fax>NA</Fax>
                <Hours>NA</Hours>
            </Contact>
            <Contact>
                <Name>Doctors - medical bug reports or claims (MCI Inc.)</Name>
                <Phone>03-6380406</Phone>
                <Fax>03-6380345</Fax>
                <Hours>NA</Hours>
            </Contact>
            <Contact>
                <Name>Focus option - all health insurance</Name>
                <Phone>03-6380204</Phone>
                <Fax>03-5244401</Fax>
                <Hours>Sunday - Thursday 20:00 to 8:30</Hours>
            </Contact>
            <Contact>
                <Name>General insurance claims department Avinoam Ike</Name>
                <Phone>03-6380429</Phone>
                <Fax>NA</Fax>
                <Hours>NA</Hours>
            </Contact>
        </Contacts>
    </Department>
    <Department>
        <Name>Service Department</Name>
        <Phone>03-6380350</Phone>
        <Hours>Sunday - Thursday 6:00 p.m. to 8:00 a.m. Fridays and holiday eves: 8:00 to 12:00</Hours>
        <Contacts>
            <Contact>
                <Name>Center and emergency assistance services 24 hours a day</Name>
                <Phone>1-800-280-555</Phone>
                <Fax>NA</Fax>
                <Hours>NA</Hours>
            </Contact>
            <Contact>
                <Name>Advice on medico - wavy insured professional liability insurance - medical(MCI Inc. )</Name>
                <Phone>03-6380346</Phone>
                <Fax>03-6380345</Fax>
                <Hours>NA</Hours>
            </Contact>
            <Contact>
                <Name>Urgent questions on Medico - Records (other than the hours at the office )</Name>
                <Phone>052-227633</Phone>
                <Fax>NA</Fax>
                <Hours>NA</Hours>
            </Contact>
            <Contact>
                <Name>Inquiries about professional liability insurance - medical</Name>
                <Phone>03-6380480</Phone>
                <Fax>03-6380461</Fax>
                <Hours>NA</Hours>
            </Contact>
            <Contact>
                <Name>Team members focus</Name>
                <Phone>1-700-700-251</Phone>
                <Fax>NA</Fax>
                <Hours>Sunday - Thursday 20:00 to 8:00</Hours>
            </Contact>
            <Contact>
                <Name>Inquiries about Medical Risk Management(MRM)</Name>
                <Phone>03-6380458</Phone>
                <Fax>03-6380345</Fax>
                <Hours>NA</Hours>
            </Contact>
        </Contacts>
    </Department>
</EssentialPhoneNumbers>
```

Comment: This would be a good tutorial for [parsing xml](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml). Your xml has a very good schema. You would need to create two model objects department and contacts. department would have a one to many and contact would have one to one relationship.

Comment: What do u mean by "specific xml structure"? This is normal XML.

Comment: just above xml structure

Comment: if u r talking about "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>" than it is fine. that is standard xml part.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you parse this xml using GDataXML

```
#define kDepartmentName  @"Name"
#define kDepartmentPhone @"Phone"
#define kDepartmentHours @"Hours"

#define kContactName    @"Name"
#define kContactPhone   @"Phone"
#define kContactFax     @"Fax"
#define kContactHours   @"Hours"

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Contacts" ofType:@"xml"];
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

GDataXMLDocument *document = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc]initWithData:fileData
                                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                             error:nil];
NSArray *departmentNodes = [document nodesForXPath:@"//EssentialPhoneNumbers/Department" error:nil];

NSMutableArray *departments = [NSMutableArray array];
for (GDataXMLElement *departmentElement in departmentNodes) {
    NSMutableDictionary *department = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSString *deptName = [[departmentElement elementsForName:kDepartmentName][0] stringValue];
    if (deptName) {
        department[kDepartmentName] = deptName;
    }

    NSString *deptPhone = [[departmentElement elementsForName:kDepartmentPhone][0] stringValue];
    if (deptPhone) {
        department[kDepartmentPhone] = deptPhone;
    }

    NSString *deptHours = [[departmentElement elementsForName:kDepartmentHours][0] stringValue];
    if (deptHours) {
        department[kDepartmentHours] = deptHours;
    }

    NSArray *contactsNodes = [departmentElement nodesForXPath:@"Contacts/Contact" error:nil];
    NSMutableArray *contacts = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (GDataXMLElement *contactElement in contactsNodes) {

        NSMutableDictionary *contact = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        NSString *contactName = [[contactElement elementsForName:kContactName][0] stringValue];
        if (contactName) {
            contact[kContactName] = contactName;
        }

        NSString *contactPhone = [[contactElement elementsForName:kContactPhone][0] stringValue];
        if (contactPhone) {
            contact[kContactPhone] = contactPhone;
        }

        NSString *contactFax = [[contactElement elementsForName:kContactFax][0] stringValue];
        if (contactFax) {
            contact[kContactFax] = contactFax;
        }

        NSString *contactHours = [[contactElement elementsForName:kContactHours][0] stringValue];
        if (contactHours) {
            contact[kContactHours] = contactHours;
        }

        if ([[contact allKeys]count]) {
            [contacts addObject:contact];
        }
    }

    if ([contacts count]) {
        department[@"Contacts"] = contacts;
    }

    if ([[department allKeys]count]) {
        [departments addObject:department];
    }

}

NSLog(@"%@",departments);
```

[Contacts.xml](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/General/Contacts.xml) file

Answer (score 0):

I'm using TBXMLParser.

Here is my code

```
 dataForParser = [queryResult dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  
    TBXML *tbxml = [TBXML tbxmlWithXMLData: dataForParser];
    TBXMLElement *root = tbxml.rootXMLElement;
    if (root) {
        TBXMLElement *item = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"item" parentElement:root];
            while (item) {
                NSString * type = [NSString stringWithFormat:[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"type" forElement:item]];
                if ([type isEqualToString:@"0"]) { 

                    Chair *ch = [[Chair alloc] init];

                    NSMutableArray * chairsAr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                    [chairsAr addObject: type];

                    ch.chairPic = [NSString stringWithFormat:[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"picture" forElement:item]];
                    ch.xChObject = [NSString stringWithFormat:[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"x" forElement:item]];
                    ch.yChObject = [NSString stringWithFormat:[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"y" forElement:item]];
                    ch.chairAngle = [NSString stringWithFormat:[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"angle" forElement:item]];

                    [allChairs addObject:ch];
```

Comment: how can it is Use full to me...!

Comment: @rajesh.k replace "item" with "department" and "type" with "contact". There may not be exact example for your case. You should try to relate  on how to use TBXML for your specific xml.

Comment: it's just an example. As Anupdas sad, you need to change elements descriptions.